Is there an open source note-taking app that has colored tabs like onenote?
I tried Joplin but it does not have this functionality.
Is there an open source note-taking app that has colored tabs like onenote for Windows or Linux (or both) ?

For which OS would you like this app recommendation?  Please edit your question and tags accordingly.  Thanks!

@EndAntisemiticHate I haded the OS tags.

The text you added is perfect.  Thanks!  Years ago, our community decided that OS tags are to be used when a particular OS is a requirement.  So when a recommendation request is for one OS or another, we leave the OS tags off.  This approach has its pros and cons, but it's what our community decided long ago.  As such, I'll leave the text you added, but remove the OS tags.  I hope that makes sense.  If not, please feel free to ask in our meta site, and I'll be happy to explain in more detail.
